# Presenting user editable fields from Wordpress Database

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently in the process of writing my first Wordpress Plugin, which is extending WPmembers. Essentially, the logic flows as follows.

1. User logs in
2. Database is referenced to see if this is their first login, if true..
3. The user is presented with an information verification screen... once verified
4. Information goes to Salesforce via POST.

My issue is with step three, while I understand displaying fields from the database, I'm unsure of how to make those fields editable by the user.

Any tips? I'm sure this has been done before but after several days of googling I've been unable to find a use case that's similar enough to mine to be put to use.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
[Adding and using custom user profile fields
Published by Justin Tadlock on September 10, 2009](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)